# user_passes_test throwing an error for anonymous user

Tags: django, python-decorators

I'm using the following mixin to check if a user is of a certain type:

```
class UserTypeXOnlyMixin(object):

    @classmethod
    def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
        view = super(UserTypeXOnlyMixin, cls).as_view(**initkwargs)
        decorator = user_passes_test(lambda u: not u.is_anonymous() and u.type == u.TYPE_X)
        return decorator(view)
```

The problem is that, even though I'm checking in the lambda function for `not u.isanonymous()` first, this function still throws an error when a logged out user visits a view where I use this mixin: `AnonymousUser has no attribute 'type'`. How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: I guess the only way it happens is if a logged out user return `is_anonymous() == False` . Are you sure it returns `True ` ?

Comment: Have you tried: `lambda u: not u.is_anonymous() and hasattr(u, 'type') and u.type == u.TYPE_X` ?